# Angular Route Always need slash if it's case insensitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-ui-router

- I created virtual directory on IIS called SA and if typed "Localhost/SA" or "Localhost/Sa/" everything working fine but if i typed the URL Caseinsensitive like this "Localhost/Sa" without slash in the end routes failed to return any page.
- if i disabled html5mode, it's getting "404 page not found" page.
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

Here's the workarounds that i used :

```
 $urlMatcherFactory.caseInsensitive(true);
 $urlMatcherFactory.strictMode(true); // or off nothing is work 

 $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
            var path = $location.path(), normalized = path;//.toLowerCase();
            template = path;

            if (path !== normalized) {
               $location.replace().path(normalized);
            }
           }
        });
```

- tried to concatenate "/" to the end of the URL by adding $urlRouterProvider.rule but it's not working also, and couldn't concatenate "/" to the end of the URL before angular bootstrap.

I am done with this issue please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I found a workaround to this issue by modify the URL before Angular bootstrap, in _Layout.cshtml file in scripts tag, by Adding trailing slash to the URL if the requested URL is ending with root application route(using baseSiteUrlPath Key) and it works fine.

```
   if (window.location.href.substr(-1) != '/' 
        && window.location.href.toLowerCase().endsWith(baseSiteUrlPath.toLowerCase().substr(0, baseSiteUrlPath.length - 1)))
        window.location.href += '/';
```